# Can I restrict a subclass from accessing a specific method of superclass?

Tags: inheritance, subclass, superclass

Say there is a class A which is inherited by subclass B.

Superclass has 2 methods A1 and A2.

My question is, can we restrict B from accessing A1?

Comment: what language are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

```
My question is, can we restrict B from accessing A1?
```

Yes, you can restrict the accessing of a1 method by simply using Access Modifier(private) like:

```
  class A
 {
    private void a1()
    {
      System.out.println("foo");

     }

    public void a2()
    {
      System.out.println("doo");

    }

}

 class B extends A
 {
   public static void main(String args[])
    {
      B obj=new B();

      obj.a1();// it would give you compile time error
    }

  }
```

In above java code, **a1** method is specified as private and it'll give compile time error.

**Bonus Point :**
A subclass does not inherit the private members of its parent class. However, if the superclass has public or protected methods for accessing its private fields, these can also be used by the subclass.

You must read: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html